# Code against Pywin32 on OS X?

Tags: python, pywin32, pythoncom

I'm working on some code that is intended to run on a Windows machine and I would like to take advantage of Windows specific modules such as Pywin32 or Pythoncom. However, I currently use OS X as my main development platform and can't merely pip install these packages since they're obviously intended to be installed on Windows boxes. Is there a way that I can import and code against these modules (similar to how I can interact with DLLs using ctypes)?

Comment: Don't think that approach is feasible. Instead, consider running Windows in a VM (Virtual Machine) and doing your development within it.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I suspected the solution would be I just wanted to have to avoid setting up and maintaining yet another development environment

Comment: Cross-platform development exacts a price in many ways. I know because I used to work at a company that did exactly that for most of the products. We were lucky in the sense that at least we had separate Mac and Windows boxes to do the work on. The extra resources required us to write portable code as much as possible. Python is a very, very good tool in that sense (as well as many others).